# Removing the "s" on singular items cause extra letter to disappear

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, information-display, plurals

> [image]

**Where the issue is?**

Go to your profile page and click on questions tab, you can see this issue in questions list which has one answer or one vote.(one view looks fine)

The same issue can be seen in all the Stack exchange Sites.

Comment: Haha you know the answer to this is that they used to just strip off the last letter of the word to make it "singular" and they recently switched to just using two different words. You just know it!!!

Comment: Looks like the code that removes the plural "s" got a bit over-enthusiastic.

Comment: I am not reproducing this, though I still find it hilarious.

Comment: @hjp Ah, wrong view. Yep, I'm seeing vots and answes everywhere!

Comment: -1 circles are not freehand

Comment: This time Jeff can't ignore it. He must be in trouble now. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ngOTH.png

Comment: @Doorknob Missing the Eeeky factor as well..

Comment: Wha d yo mea? I can' se an bu.

Comment: This should be tagged [meta-tag:plura].

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. It'll be fixed in build rev 2013.7.30.1289 (meta) / 2013.7.30.902 (sites).

As it happens some views got smart over time (thanks to fixing pluralization bugs in the past I guess..) and include own pluralization logic. This particular one had a one liner in a helper somewhere similar to `count == 1 ? str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1) : str`. Code like this is becoming obsolete as we're moving views to our [localization API](http://mattjibson.com/blog/2013/02/28/careers-localization-part-2-api/), and is easily missed when *batch* replacing hard coded strings. So the problem was that pluralization was performed twice, once via the API and then in the view.

I guess we're now paying the price for fixing pluralization in the past and Jeff was right all along!

But anyway, watch out for those, winter is coming...

Comment: Is that URL to moonspeak intentional? There are no references to "moonspeak" on that page!