# Welcome back, user. Click here to get error 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, 404-not-found

When I visit a rarely-used Stack Exchange site (homepage, e.g., drupal.stackexchange.com) I get the familiar banner:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

in which the link "Click here" has URL such as

```
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/%24url%24
```

Unsurprisingly, that page is 404.

Reproduced on several sites (Drupal, Gardening, Wordpress) in Chrome 37.

Also reproduced in Firefox 32.0.3 on multiple sites (Data Science, Gardening). But on Beer.SE the URL was different from the above:

```
http://beer.stackexchange.com/help/%24url%24
```

How odd.

Comment: Wow, that's $adjective$.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome 38 on Meta.SE and StackOverflow. I have no idea how I'm getting it; it appears seemingly at random.

Comment: Happens to me, too, consistently. Boardgames, writers, arqade, programmers, ELL, Emacs, CogSci.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was an issue with [Moonspeak](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236797/115866), our localization engine. Fixed now (or rather, worked around until the underlying issue is fixed) and works fine again. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This looks like a very recent regression.  Specifically, looking at the current version of [full-anon.en.js](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full-anon.en.js), the code that injects this message is, indeed, clearly bugged:

```js
message += returnTo
    ? '<a href="%24url%24">Click here<\/a> to return to your last location.'
    : '<a href="%24url%24">Click here<\/a> to refresh the page.';
```

However, the same code, in the old version I had cached in my browser, used to look like this:

```js
message += returnTo
    ? (function(n){return'<a href="'+n.url+'">Click here<\/a> to return to your last location.'})({url:"javascript:window.location='"+returnTo+"'"})
    : (function(n){return'<a href="'+n.url+'">Click here<\/a> to refresh the page.'})({url:"javascript:location.reload(true)"});
```

So, yeah, looks like somebody needs to revert the code to a working state.

---

Ps. While I expect this to be fixed quickly, just for fun I whipped up a user script fix and added it to the [devel branch](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/tree/devel) of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).  Here's the code:

```js
SOUP.hookAjax( /^\/users\/login\/global\b/, function ( event, xhr, settings ) {
    var match = /[?&]returnurl=((https?:\/\/|\/)[^&]*)/.exec( location.search );
    if (match) {
        var url = decodeURIComponent( match[1] );
        var jsCode = "location=" + JSON.stringify( url );
    } else {
        var jsCode = "location.reload(true)";
    }
    var jsUrl = 'javascript:' + encodeURIComponent( jsCode );
    $('#overlay-header a[href="%24url%24"]').attr( 'href', jsUrl );
} );
```

As a slight bonus, by using such fancy new techniques as regexps and `JSON.stringify()`, I managed to make this hotfix somewhat cleaner and more robust that the actual SE code it replaces.  If you're feeling adventurous and want to test it, you can [install](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/devel/SOUP.user.js) the development version of SOUP using a user script manager like GreaseMonkey or Tampermonkey.