# “1 more comments” in the iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, plurals

At the risk of invoking [Jeff Atwood’s wrath…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236746/226928)

Here’s a (truncated) screenshot from the iOS app:

[image]

In this case, the string should read “1 more comment”, not “1 more comments”.

Spotted in v1.3.0 build from the App Store, on iOS 8.3 (12F70) and an iPhone 5s.

Answer (score 3):

This bugs will be fixed in the next build.