# Typo in Stack Snippets: "Javascript" should be "JavaScript"

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, stack-snippets

[image]

That's not a pluralization bug, so I shouldn't [expect Jeff coming to my house with a giant "S"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236746/310998), right?

Comment: You are dealing with a giant S...

Comment: @Zizouz212 It's just uppercase, not giant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix going live in the next build.