# Question summary tooltip shows incorrect text when a question has only one (accepted) answer

Tags: bug, design, tooltips, plurals, question-summary

Currently, this is the tooltip you see when hovering over the green box in the question summary:

[image: Tooltip showing the text "one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer"]

> *one of the answers* was accepted as the correct answer

When there is only *one* answer (which is accepted), this tooltip seems incorrect as "one of the answer**s**" suggests that there is more than one answer to the question.

This should be changed to something more general. The best suggestion would be to change it to:

> *An answer to this question* was accepted as the correct answer

Can this be fixed?

Comment: The tooltip also fails to meet the modern Stacks guideline that it should be in sentence case (a reversal of the prior stance of having everything lowercase).

Comment: Related: [What is the story of Jeff Atwood and the pluralization 'Bug'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/what-is-the-story-of-jeff-atwood-and-the-pluralization-bug)